# How to boot into Ubuntu?

Tags: windows

I have a Windows 7 computer (I am typing this on it). I put Ubuntu on a USB flash drive, and installed it as I was instructed. After rebooting, it booted back into Windows without asking me if I wanted to boot into Windows or Ubuntu. I booted from the USB drive, and it acted as if I had never installed Ubuntu. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe during the installation the Grub wasn't properly installed. Maybe if you use the flash drive again and try to install the Ubuntu, it will tell if it's installed or not. If it is, maybe you can try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to interrupt the boot process by pressing e.g. the escape key or one of the function keys to get into GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely positive that you installed Ubuntu you could try the [boot rescue disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)

This will reinstall your grub and make it visible for 10 seconds during each boot (you can change this with [grub customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)).
If it doesn't work you'll have to reinstall your Ubuntu.